# Shortcut is not getting created when i run a batch script

Tags: uwp, shortcut-file

I am trying to create a shortcut using this script but due to some admin rights issues, it is not getting created.

Is there any way I can run this script with admin permission in UWP?

```
powershell "$s=(New-Object -COM WScript.Shell).CreateShortcut('%userprofile%\Desktop\app_name.lnk');$s.TargetPath='shell:AppsFolder\App_Package_name_fwsgascccvxc0!App';$s.Save()"
```

Comment: The PowerShell code actually works just fine for me. I don't think it was working last week though. What OS version are you on?

Comment: How do i delete that shortcut after uninstallation of the app?

Comment: You can listen to uninstall notifications on the PC, but that requires running code all the time. You could also just periodically check if the app still exists, and delete the shortcut if not. (Note that if the user copies / moves the shortcut, or creates their own, you will continue to have a problem).

Comment: yes, thats not a good solution. I saw an article about rescap3:DesktopAppMigration, but that's also not working  https://www.syncfusion.com/ebooks/msix-succinctly/packaging-your-applications-with-visual-studio

Comment: I am not sure if we can use this or not. Do you know if we can use this?